# Mongo Template Results not getting Mapped after Spring Boot Upgrade

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

After upgrading from Spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE to 2.4, the following mapping does not work & returns null for all the mapped values. I'm unable to find any mongo documentation describing any update to aggregation or mapping. However the rawResults contains the required data. I've tried changing the mongo versions, spring boot version upgrades.

The same code works without a issue in spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE version.

```
   final Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("id.cid").is(cId)),
            group("sId.assignmentId", "status").count().as("total"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sId.assignmentId", "status"));
    final AggregationResults<StatusSummeryDTO> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
            Submission.class, StatusSummeryDTO.class);

    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after MongoDB driver version being changed from 3.x to 4.x in the result DTO class we will need to specify the exact field value using `@Field` annotation. Unlike in 3.x it does not map automatically which resulted in the above issue.

Since there are breaking changes in the aggregation when moving from 3.x to 4.x I thought that might be the issue. to be on the better side I've changed my code to be compatible with 4.x using new classes as follows.

```
    MatchOperation match = match(Criteria.where("id.cid").is(cId));
    GroupOperation group = group("sId.assignmentId", "status").count().as("total");
    SortOperation sort = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sId.assignmentId", "status");

    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match, group, sort);
    AggregationResults<StatusSummeryDTO> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Submission.class, StatusSummeryDTO.class);

    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```